# Не могу запустить XAMP, мешает какой-то сервер от винды (Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 занимает 80ый порт)

Tags: windows, сеть, iis, localhost, http-server

Мне нужно поднять Xamp со всеми его пхп, апачем и прочим. Но 80ый порт занят этим:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что это такое, а главное, как его отключить на рсскоязычной системе? Как он называется то? Я нашел на одном сайте это:

> After some fruitless Google searches, I found a stray post noting that this could be the Web Deployment Service Agent. As a former Windows user, of many years now, I can’t even comment (or care) what this service is for, all I can do is tell you how I disabled it:
> 1)Open your Control Panel (Start > Control Panel)
> 2)Change the view setting from Category to Small or Large Icons
> 3)Open Administrative Tools
> 4)Open Services
> 5)Find “Web Deployment Service Agent” in the list
> 6)Right click and choose Properties
> 7)Click Stop
> 8)Change it’s Start Up value to “Manual”
> 9)Hit Apply/OK to save the changes
> 10)Go to WAMP and restart all services
> This should do it.

Но никакого Web Deployment Service Agent я у себя в списках служб не вижу. Как это выклчить?

Comment: что говорит `netstat -a` и `netstat -l`?

Comment: Уже нашел ее по PID. Это какой то там System. Говорят, его не так то просто отключить и нельзя его отключать. Так она и называется - System. Мне кажется, в этом виноват IIS и какие то мои прошлые попытки его установить и кое что на нем запустить. Я нашел эту https://myhelpit.ru/index.php?id=163 статью. Лично я не стал запариваться и запустил апач на другом порту. Но может кому то потом поможет.

Comment: Первый раз слышу о том, что что-то работает, просто так занимает 80 порт и нельзя отключать. Вам виднее.

Comment: читайте мануалы на иис. привязку удалите с 80го порта. и будет апач у вас работать. еще можно попробовать настроить http.sys через netsh.